# Why does Tika 2.1 app ignore text in a .txt file?

Tags: apache-tika

I am processing a file using Tika 2.1 from the command line under Ubuntu 20.04 using the following command:

```
java -jar tika-app-2.1.0.jar -t test.txt
```

The file is a pure text ANSI file (all the chars are 0x0 thru 0x7f). As hard as this is to believe, Tika 2.1 app is ignoring all characters when a specific string is present is the text file.

Here is the text file:

```
From:
Sent:
text

this is a test
testing 

next
last
```

And here is the output:

```
this is a test
testing

next
last
```

To show that this is a pure ANSI text file with no formatting, no Unicode 2-bytes sequences, etc., here is the output of the 'od' command:

```
0000000 7246 6d6f 0d3a 530a 6e65 3a74 0a0d 6574
0000020 7478 0a0d 0a0d 6874 7369 6920 2073 2061
0000040 6574 7473 0a0d 6574 7473 6e69 2067 0a0d
0000060 0a0d 656e 7478 0a0d 616c 7473
```

However, if I simply change the "Sent:" to "sent:" the output is:

```
From:
sent:
text

this is a test
testing

next
last
```

I've been troubleshooting this issue and do not see the connection. If I append "Sent:" to the first line:

```
From: Sent:
Sent:
text

this is a test
testing 

next
last
```

The results are:

```
this is a test
testing

next
last
```

But if I alter "Sent:" to be "\Sent" on the second line, I get this output:

```
From: Sent:
\Sent:
text

this is a test
testing

next
last
```

And this file:

```
From: Sent:
Sent:
Sent:
text

this is a test
testing 

next
last
```

Results in this output:

```
this is a test
testing

next
last
```

But if I place "Sent:" in the first line or a simple  (0d 0a) as the first two bytes, the output is fine. Why is it the start of the second line seems to matter, as well as the uppercase or lowercase working but not "Sent:"? Why does preceding "Sent" with a "\" make it work? I've also tried this on a different machines - one running Ubuntu 18.04 and running the jar on a Windows 10 system - both with same results.

What is going on with the basic Tika response to a very simply text file? I have not altered the jar in any way. This is the jar file as downloaded from the Apache Tika site. What am I missing?

Any information is very much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like Tika might be interpreting this as an email - if you fetch the metadata do you find the rest of the info there?

Comment: @Gagravarr: When I run detect it shows that it is a message/rfc822 type email. But all the files I have are text files that contain the content of an OCR operation. I only want to operate on the text and have the metadata stored separately. So I do only want to have TIKA provide the text from the files after which I can then translate and analyze. If Tika only allows for its own interpretation instead of using the .txt extension, it will not work for my application. Is there a way to force the detect to the file extension (ie. txt)?

Comment: It's interesting because if I add 0d 0a to the beginning of the file it detects a text file and works fine.

Comment: If you know it is a text file, you can skip `AutoDetectParser` and call the text parser directly. Alternately, set the content type property on the metadata and then call `DefaultParser` and it'll call the text parser for you

Comment: @Gagravarr - Sounds good. I have been using the server mode and will follow your advice with using the API. Tx for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tika is interpreting the text as an email. This specific example was a text extraction of an email and includes certain keywords (e.g. "From:" and "Sent:" in specific positions). That is why when other characters are added at the start of the file, it defaults to interpreting it as a pure text file.

I had thought that the order of interpretation was first based on the ".txt" extension and then analysis of the content (which in this case does not have any metadata with this text file). But that does not appear to be the case here. It seems that analysis is the first order, before it considers the ".txt" extension.

The example was being run through Tika running as a server. Going forward I will use the Tika API and follow the suggestions provided by the commenter (@Gagravarr) by skipping a call to AutoDetectParser,setting the content type property on the metadata and call DefaultParser all via the API.

Tx to @Gagravarr for finding a solution.

Comment: You can also do this via Tika Server by adding the content type in the HTTP request to achieve the same result:

`curl -T test.txt http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Content-Type: text/plain"`